# How to traverse a multidimensional array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Given a multidimensional array A = MxMxMx...xM, where ndims(A)=n. My problem can be described by the following pseudo-code:

```
tmp = A(i, :, :, :, ..., :)
sum(tmp(:)) i = 1, ... M
tmp = A(:, i, :, :, ..., :)
sum(tmp(:)) i = 1, ... M
    ...
tmp = A(:, :, :, :, ..., i)
sum(tmp(:)) i = 1, ... M
```

Let me use an example to illustrate it.

```
C = 1:81;
A = reshape(C, 3, 3, 3, 3);
result = zeros(3, 4);
for i = 1 : 3
    tmp = A(i, :, :, :);
    result(1, i) = sum(tmp(:));
end
for i = 1 : 3
    tmp = A(:, i, :, :);
    result(2, i) = sum(tmp(:));
end
for i = 1 : 3
    tmp = A(:, :, i, :);
    result(3, i) = sum(tmp(:));
end
for i = 1 : 3
    tmp = A(:, :, :, i);
    result(4, i) = sum(tmp(:));
end
```

I really don't know how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This is not easy to understand. Can you illustrate with a 3x3x3 matrix?

Comment: @RobertP.I've added an example. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
sumsAlongDims = zeros( M, n ); % M sums per dim
for dim = 1:n
    tmp = permute( A, [dim 1:(dim-1) (dim+1):n] ); % bring dim to front
    tmp = reshape( tmp, M, [] ); % make it 2D
    sumsAlongDims(:, dim) = sum( tmp, 2 ); % gives to the m sums along each coordinate of dimension "dim" at once
end
```